# hosting in office365 for an app created with visual studio 2013

Tags: office-365

I'm creating projects for sharepoint 2013 with visual studio 2013 and I've found that I need a provider to host the webpages, can I host the pages in a office 365 site? I mean, there is a part of the project that is installed in office 365 but it seems that the aspx pages would reside out of office 365.

Comment: what is the type of your page? Application page or site page?

Comment: The main idea at least is to create a non office 365 application, could really be anything (you are not bound to .net for example, but it will be more difficult to work with SharePoint data)

Comment: I would like that the app were asp .net webforms.